# Auction Expiration process using Php(CodeIgniter) Mysql Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I'm developing an auction website. It is like: Auction is consists of X number of cars (let's say 10 cars in an auction). I have tables for auction, bid and product. My cronjob checks if any auction is ready to go live. If there is any then it flag the auction as active and update the bid time in product table. 
Every product stays for 1 minute if in that time someone bid on the product time resets. if Minute is over it bring the next car for auction.

I'm wondering, if no user opens the window how i'm gonna expire the auction. All the request go from client. I'm using sockets for biding process.
Thank you

Comment: Isn't that what your cronjob is doing?

Comment: nope. my cronjob just active the auction. Making it unactive requires all the cars in that auction must be sold or unsold. I'm stuck at how i'm gonna expire single car if there is no user on the site

Comment: Auctions expiry based on time, not on any user. Your every car has its own time. And your cron will check the if times up it will change the status.

In short use cronjob for handling auction expiry.

Comment: i'm not adding car end time just the time when it got first bid. so i must add the end time too. every car expires in 1 minute if there is no one bidding. So my should be set at 1 minute? wouldn't it be cruel for server or it would be fine?

Comment: I suppose it depends a lot on the business domain. Your question is rather broad and thus suitable for an answer on an architectural level, but for that kind of advice a lot more details are required. Basically I'd say you can choose between expiring the previous action when someone expresses interest in the next item, or (re)schedule a job to run in one minute when you're starting the auction. Either could make sense but it depends a lot on missing context.

Comment: We set auction's time i.e when it will start. every car has default 1 minute until it expires. there could be multiple auction at the same time. let's say Florida Auction, Texas Auction. There are 10 cars each in both auction. Every car has 1 minute of time and if in that 1 minute someone bid on the car, timer will reset otherwise car is unsold and the car at number 2 will come for bidding. The problem is how would i expire Cars if there is no user. I'm only storing the time when car was brought on to the auction. i don't have idea how to make 2nd car available for auction

Comment: from you comments i understand that I have to store end time which will when auction started + 1 minute. and I have to set up a cron which will check if end_time < now, so it will expire the car and will bring the second car to the auction and vice versa..

Comment: Just one more little help will it be fine if I set cron for 1 minute?